# Is there an app where you can control your phone w only hardware buttons

Tags: broken-screen

My phones touch screen is broken, it only responds for like 2 secs everytime i turn on with power button.
Need somethin like double press vol key equals swipe left, and other key is right. Hold for swipe down up.
Thankss

Comment: Xposed Edge and Xposed Additions app can do that, but they require root access and Xposed Framework installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Use bluetooth to connect something like gamepad or keyboard to control your phone, but I should have changed screen or bought a new phone.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone has OTG,

- Plug in a USB Mouse & Keyboard.